# Proof of Smith Normal Form as a Generalization of Rank-Nullity Theorem

Tags: ring-theory, modules

For any matrix $A$ with entries in a PID, there exist invertible matrices $P$ and $Q$ such that $B = PAQ$, where $B$ is in Smith normal form. This theorem is usually proved by using elementary row/column operations. However, in the case where the entries of $A$ are in a field, there is a short proof which is basically just the rank-nullity theorem [interpret $A$ as a linear map from $\mathbb{F}^m$ to $\mathbb{F}^n$, choose a basis $\{v_{1}, \ldots , v_{k}\}$ for the kernel of $A$ and extend it to a basis for $\mathbb{F}^m$, and finally use $\{A(v_{1}), \ldots , A(v_{k})\}$ as a basis for $\mathbb{F}^n$ (extending it as necessary)]. Of course, the rank-nullity theorem does not hold over rings, but is there some way to generalize the ideas of this proof for any PID, perhaps by passing to its field of fractions?